# Replace Wordpress shortcode containing id with html markup using the id

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace, shortcode

I'm building a filter plugin in Wordpress and I'm replacing some plugin specific tags with bits of html.

Example: `[VIDEO ID=12]` will be replaced via preg_replaced in this function

```
function display_video($text){
   
   $pattern = '/\[VIDEO ID\=\d+\]/';
   
   $text=preg_replace($pattern,get_video_block($id),$text);
   
   return $text;
}
```

I'm not exactly sure how to make sure I supply the correct (`$id`) param to my `get_video_block()` function for each replacement occurrence.

There's no real loop going on other than inside the `preg_replace()` function so, how would I supply that value?

For more context, `get_video_block()` function:

```
function get_video_block($id){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->show_errors();
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "video_manager";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $table_name . " WHERE `index` = '$id'"; 
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);
    
    $results = $results[0];
    
    $returnString = '<div class="vidBlock">';
        $returnString .= $results['embed_code'];
        
        $returnString .= '<div class="voteBar">';
            $returnString .= $results['vote_text'];
            $returnString .= '<input type="button" value="YES" class="voteButton">';
            $returnString .= '<input type="button" value="NO" class="voteButton">';
        $returnString .= '</div>';
        
        $returnString .= $results['title'] . '<br>';
        $returnString .= $results['description'] . '<br>';
    
    $returnString .= '</div>';
    
    return $returnString;
    
}
```

Comment: just curious, if it's a wordpress filter with [code attrib=""] pattern, why dont you use wordpress shortcode API?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: What is `get_video_block()` doing?

Comment: I'm not using it because I never heard of it before now ;)

Comment: @Felix... It's building a little video module.

Comment: Just a little side-note: it would be useful to escape the table name in your `get_video_block()` function whether or not the prefix can be trusted.

Comment: And escape the `$id` column as well.  Sure, this particular case may be forced to be an int by the regex, but in general there's a possible SQL Injection vulnerability there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for that purpose. You'll also need to wrap `\d+` in `(` parentheses `)` so it can be captured and used in the callback function.

```
function display_video($text) {
    $callback = create_function('$matches', 'return get_video_block($matches[1])');
    return preg_replace_callback('/\[VIDEO ID\=(\d+)\]/', $callback, $text);
}
```

Note that `$matches[1]` is used because `$matches[0]` contains the entire string matched by the regular expression.

Erwin's comment may be of use to you — WordPress has a [shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) that manages parsing of shortcodes for you, so you can concentrate on dealing with what you want to do with the shortcode attributes.

Answer (score 0):

@BoltClock's answer is correct, but `create_function()` is a little old fashioned now.

Pass the captured id to the helper function via an anonymous function inside of `preg_replace_callback()`.

The helper function's returned string will be used to replace the entire matched shortcode.

Since no limit was declared for `preg_replace_callback()`, it will make potentially multiple replacements.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dAUbG))

```
function get_video_block($id) {
    return "***replacement text for $id***";
}

function display_video($text) {
   return preg_replace_callback(
              '/\[VIDEO ID=(\d+)]/',
              function($m) {
                  return get_video_block($m[1]);
              },
              $text
          );
}

echo display_video("Here is a video [VIDEO ID=33] to watch");
```

Output:

```
Here is a video ***replacement text for 33*** to watch
```

P.s. As @azureru mentioned in a comment, this does seem like a good candidate for implementing Wordpress's shortcode api. http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API