# Creating a very simple shortcode solution in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, shortcode

I want to construct a very basic shortcode solution in a simple non-WordPress website I am maintaining, to allow users to enter content that will be pulled from a database and rendered to screen, allowing them to create a href buttons.

I've seen various classes for this but want to do this in just a line or two of code if possible.

Only they will enter via a shortcode with this format:

[BUTTON link="www.test.com" label="Click here"]

So far I have this which doesn't extract the attributes properly:

```
$copy=preg_replace('/\[(BUTTON )(.*?)\]/', '<a href="$2">$1</a>', $copy);
```

Can anyone advise?

Comment: I would use `preg_replace_callback` with a simple regular expression to match the entire shortcode (with all the attributes in a single capture group), and do the parsing of the attributes in a separate function with something like a tokenizer

Comment: Related: [Replace Wordpress shortcode containing id with html markup using the id](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3568229/2943403) and [Regex to parse custom shortcode substrings in article and generate array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64301844/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you don't actually want to capture the BUTTON, but the link and the label.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6FYoE))

```
echo preg_replace(
         '/\[button link="([^"]+)" label="([^"]+)"]/i',
         '<a href="$1">$2</a>',
         $text
     );
```

Comment: That is amazing thanks @mickmackusa.   Only thing I wonder if its easy to make it so that the order of the attributes specified can be either way around?  Currently it has to be link first then label.

Comment: Certainly do-able, but I recommend that you insist on strict formatting.  I'd probably use `preg_replace_callback()` with a condition and some more capture groups.

Answer (score -1):

maybe check how WordPress implemented it?

https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.0.2/src/wp-includes/shortcodes.php

and if the above link doesn't work, check up WordPress core , how they implemented the short code functionality on GitHub.

Comment: If this link changes/dies, then your answer is useless.  This is why Stack Overflow never wants link-only answers.